# How to expose actuator health status of dependent services?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 microservices running and started via docker-compose, serviceB is dependent on serviceA

1. serviceA
2. serviceB

Both the above services have their health endpoints exposed as

- http://host:port1/serviceA/actuator/health
- http://host:port2/serviceB/actuator/health

How to expose serviceA's health status as part of serviceB's health status?

Comment: can't you do that via writing an `InfoContributor`?